# How to uniform spread every k values over a collection of n values with k <= n?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I've a collection of k elements. I need to spread them uniformly random into a collection of n elements, where k <= n.

So for example, with this k-collection (with k = 3):

```
{ 3, 5, 6 }
```

and give n = 7, a valid permutation result (with n = 7 elements) could be:

```
{ 6, 5, 6, 3, 3, 6, 5}
```

Notice that every item within the k-collection must be used into the permutation.

So this is not a valid result:

```
{ 6, 3, 6, 3, 3, 6, 6} // it lacks "5"
```

What's the fast way to accomplish this?

Comment: "uniformly random" and "every item within the k-collection must be used into the permutation." are mutually exclusive

Comment: You may do it the obvious way, then start again if the condition is not satisfied, in the case where chances of failure are small, (like generating a [random number close to `RAND_MAX`](http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html),) but as noted, this will be not be UAR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of.

1. Add one of each item to the array. So with your example, your initial array is `[3,5,6]`. This guarantees that every element is represented at least once.
2. Then, successively pick an element at random, and add it to the array. Do this `n-3` times. (i.e. fill the array with randomly selected items from the list of elements)
3. [Shuffle the array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

This takes O(n) to fill the array, and O(n) to shuffle it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have a

```
std::vector<int> input;
```

that contains the `k` elements you need to spread and

```
std::vector<int> output;
```

that will be filled with `n` elements.

I used the following approach for a similiar problem. (Edit: Thinking about it,  here is a simpler and probably faster version than the original)

1. First we satisfy the condition that every item from `input` must occurr at least once in `output`. Therefore we put every element from `input` once into `output`.

   ```
   output.resize(n); // fill with n 0's
   std::copy(input.begin(), input.end(), output.begin()); // fill k first items
   ```
2. Now we can fill up the remaining `n - k` slots with random elements from `input`:

   ```
   std::random_device rd;
   std::mt19937 rand(rd());                        // get seed from random device
   std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0, k - 1); // for random numbers in [0, k-1]

   for(size_t i = k; i < n; i++) {
       output[i] = input[dist(rand)];
   }
   ```
3. At the end shuffle the whole thing, to randomize the position of the first `k` elements:

   ```
   std::random_shuffle(output.begin(), output.end(), rand);
   ```

---

I hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: Isnt dist(0, k - 1); 
instead of n - 1?

Answer (score 0):

You can try just randomly put values to ur n-collection, then verify if it contains  all k-collection values if not try again. However it's not always fast xd  
 u can also put missing values in a random place of n-collection, but  remember to verify again.

Comment: not very faster approch. and the process could technically never end :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply make an array of the k elements, say {3,5,6} in the given example. Make a variable counter, which is zero initially. If you want to spread it over n elements, simply iterate over n elements of array with the counter incrementing as

```
counter=(counter+1)%k;
```

Comment: this won't work I think, since I will every time get the same number of subset added to the n-collection.i.e. { 6, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5} would be impossible...